# PsychoPy: How to change number of elements in DotStim or ElementArrayStim?

Tags: psychopy

Say I generated a `dots = psychopy.visual.DotStim`. Is it possible to change the number of dots later? `dots.nDots = 5` leads to an error on the next `dots.draw()` because the underlying matrices don't match:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jonas/Documents/projects/work pggcs/experiment/dots.py", line 32, in <module>
    dots_right.draw()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psychopy/visual/dot.py", line 279, in draw
    self._update_dotsXY()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psychopy/visual/dot.py", line 362, in _update_dotsXY
    self._verticesBase[:,0] += self.speed*numpy.reshape(numpy.cos(self._dotsDir),(self.nDots,))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 218, in reshape
    return reshape(newshape, order=order)
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

The same is true of `psychopy.visual.ElementArrayStim` for which setting `stim.nElements = 5` similarly results in an error on the next draw.

A solution is of course to instantiate a whole new `DotStim` or `ElementArrayStim` every time the number of dots/elements should change but this seems too heavy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be fixed for the `DotStim`:

```
dots.nDots = 5
dots._dotsDir = [0]*dots.nDots
dots. _verticesBase = dots._newDotsXY(dots.nDots)
```

This set movement of all dots to 0 but you can change that value to whatever you like or specify for individual dots. This is a hack which will likely break if you modify other aspects of the DotStim.

I haven't figured out a solution for `ElementArrayStim`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be nice to be able to do this but I haven't gotten around to it. The code that has to be run when the nDots/nElements changes is pretty close to starting from scratch with a new stimulus.**init** so adding this in 'correctly' probably means some refactoring (move a lot of the **init** code into setNDots() and then call it from **init**).

There's an additional potential issue which is that the elements might have changed (e.g. the user has set the orientations) and then updates the number of elements. Which ones do we remove? And what orientation do we give those that we add? (This is less of an issue for DotStim though)

Basically, the issue is a little thorny and hasn't ben a priority for me.

Comment: Yes, that was also my thoughts when I looked at the code. That's why I didn't submit a pull request. I guess we could remove dots at random or add randomly picked copies of existing "dots". This would be close to the desired behavior in 80% of the use cases? But for now I just wanted this dirty fix to be googleable.